# AS3 alarm clock understanding

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, clock, alarm

I have some problem =(
I am very new to as3 and I am stuck! please help me T_T)

Right after the code `(timeText.text = "ALARM!!!";)`
I added one more line so that it can play a sound rather than just showing `"ALARM"` which was this

```
var s:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("test.mp3"));
```

I put `test.mp3` in the same directory but it doesn't play the sound when time is up to alarm.

Comment: This is a *very low quality* post ...

Comment: You need to provide more information about your problem. Mainly, more code and the context where the code is executed. What have you tried? Do you get any errors? Are you calling `s.play()` on the sound?
Here's an example of using the Sound object to play a sound: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("myFavSong.mp3"));
mySound.play();
```

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/

This tutorial helps you to understand how to play sound in flash.